# Make call on number click

Tags: android

I need a little help.
I have ,in my app, a textView which contains a phone number,and i want to make a call when i click that phone number.
I've already accomplished that:

```
sitePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String number = "tel:" + sitePhone.getText().toString().trim();
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that sometimes i have on my text view 2 or 3 phone numbers.Something like this: "07456443345 FAR: 0745456334".I take the phone number string from the database so it cannot be altered.
Any ides of how i can make a call on each number click? thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you should replace your `sitePhone.getText().toString().trim()` by something to extract the phone number you need. This is very basic String manipulation (and thus, you question has nothing to do with "make a call" or "Android", but it's about plain Java. Did I miss something ?

Comment: also you can use the`String.split` and differentiate between the different numbers. (you should also use regex to trim all the letters and punctuation)

Comment: actually it has everything to do with android.(which apparently is very smart:) ).I just found the answer.All you need to do is to add the property :  android:autoLink="phone" in  your xml (in your text view) and android can handle the rest.i don't even need the set on click lisenner

Comment: if you solve your issue, then post reply to your own question and mark it as answer when SO allows you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a simple answer:
 `android:autoLink="phone"`   will to the trick.