# Getting my android app to launch the call feature after a button press

Tags: java, android

what I need to do is, after the user presses a specific button, make my app launch the phones keypad with a variable phone number (that varies based on result) inserted into it.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Else can anyone point me in the right direction as I can't seem to find the right wording for this question to see if it's already been resolved!

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118314/make-call-on-number-click

Comment: You might want to consider allowing the user to edit the number instead of calling directly; just good user experience

Comment: @Eenvincible the app opens the phone dialer with the number loaded into it, but the user explicitly has to make the call, meaning they can do whatever they want with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more information take a look at the official android docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

You can probably do something like this if you want it to call automatically:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "PHONE_HERE"));
startActivity(intent);`

Also add the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```